# How to query data from Firebase to create an IN-APP report?

Tags: database, firebase, report

I am building a simple app using ***firebase***, and i would like to query data from firebase to show in-app reports.

For example:

I have patient profiles in the database with insurance provider information. I would like to provide a report of how many patients have one insurance provider over another. And another report showing how many patient I have added to the database on a given day over a period of time.

An example of the **patient profile data** is below:

[image: Patient profile data]

An example of the **patient chart** I wanna build is below:

[image: Patient chart]

I would really really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a npm package for this. It might help https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-reporting